# jslint ignore Expected '{' errors

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a lot of `Expected '{' and instead saw 'blah'` errors that spit out when I run my scripts through jslint. Is there an option that ignores this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no options to ignore this unless you edit the source of jslint and remove this particular warning. However, it is highly recommended not to ignore this rule.

Comment: I know it's not recommended, but this particular coding style actually reduces your file size, and still maintains readability, regardless of what crock says. I ended just hacking the source myself, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

no. crocky is a curmudgeon js nazi.;-) there is a vs addin on codeplex that i added an ignore feature to though. the addin is still kinda buggy but works well enough. I haven't been able to get contact with the owner to get on the project so havent put a lot more time into it. anyway see [here](http://www.codeplex.com/jslint) and get the patch from the patches tab

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with the latest version of sublime-jslint, I just told it to ignore these errors by adding to the "ignore_errors" option:

```
"ignore_errors":
[
    "Expected '{' and instead saw"
],
```

Now whenever I run sublime-jslint on my files, I get:

```
jslint: ignored 5 errors.
```